# Relationship between derivatives of two functions and between anti-derivatives of two functions

Tags: calculus

*Given that $f,g: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ are differentiable with $f(x)\geq g(x),a\leq x \leq b$. What kind of relationship can we observe between derivatives $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$? Furthermore, what can be said for $F(x)=\int_a^xf(s)ds$, and $G(x)=\int_a^x g(s)ds$?*

I first thought, I should simply state different rules (sum rule, product rule, but not quotient since none of the functions is defined as different from zero) and solve them for $f'(x)$ or $g'(x)$, respectively. But we would obtain different expressions and none of them would consider the extra information $f(x)\geq g(x)$, that we are given. Any hints in which direction I should look? The second part (anti-derivatives)  can probably be solved analogously.

Comment: Think of derivative as slope of the tangent line at a point $x$, that is($f'(x)$). Now $f\geq g$ that means when you picture the functions one of them lies above the other. But when you look at the derivative one of the functions might have a steeper slope and the other a less steeper slope. So with your given assumption about the functions you cannot say much about the derivatives(the presented answers show examples). But one the other hand you can say stuff about the integral of those functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $f(x) \geq g(x)$ does not seem to give enough information to derive any useful relationship between $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$. For example consider that for $f(x)=x-a$ and $g(x)=-x+a$ you get $f'(x) \geq g'(x)$, but for $f(x)=-x+b$ and $g(x)=x-b$ you get $f'(x) \leq g'(x)$.

On the other hand from $f(x) \geq g(x)$ you can see that $F(x) \geq G(x)$, for example by viewing the definite integral as an area under the curve given by function graph.